# Put an array of images in a tabular format

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, flask

I would like output an array of image in a tabular format please.

As of yet, I am able to out images on the flask webpage in an unordered format.

```js
var imge ='{{label3}}'; 
imge=imge.replace(/&#39;/g,'');
imge=imge.replace('[','');
imge=imge.replace(']','');
imge=imge.split(',')
console.log(image)
var j=0;
for (i=0; i<90; i=i+10)
{
    path = '/static/adv/';
    var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src=path + "adv0-"+i+".0.PNG?{{time}}";
    var confidence = document.createElement('span');
    confidence.innerText=imge[j]; 
    document.getElementById('AdversialExample').appendChild(image);
    document.getElementById('AdversialExample').appendChild(confidence);
    j=j+1;
}
```

I would like to output the following array of images in a tabular format.

Thanks in advance.